# Domain & sub-domain redirection

Tags: dns, domain, redirection, subdomain

I plan to setup a site `domain1.com` but want all the traffic coming to it redirected to `domain2.com`.

If I do that, will there be any issue in creating `subdomain1.domain1.com` and `subdomain2.domain1.com` ?

Thanks !

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "all traffic" (SMTP? SNMP? HTTP? RPC?).  What kind of redirect?  DNS-level, HTTP-level, network-level?

Comment: I meant HTTP traffic. Sorry I should have been more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Domains don't deal with "traffic", they're just pointing out the IP address to contact a server. You can obviously set a different IP adress for `topdomain.tld` and `subdomain.topdomain.com`. In your case you even want to alias `domain1.com` to `domain2.com`, with a CNAME for exemple. You can then add a DNS A/AAAA record for `subdomain1.domain1.com` and `subdomain2.domain1.com`. DNS zone will look like something like this:

```
domain1.com. CNAME domain2.com.
subdomain1.domain1.com. A 255.255.255.255
subdomain2.domain1.com. A 255.255.255.255
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer, for HTTP, is No.  `domain1.com` and `domain2.com` can have either the same A record or different A records in DNS.  The web server you land on by using `http://domain1.com` has to have rules that rewrite the URI to be `http://domain2.com` and send a 301 Moved Permanently redirect response.  This will cause the name to change in the browser and reload the new site.

This has no effect on domain names like `subdomain1.domain1.com` which can be added with their own A records or even a CNAME.

Note: For *real* domain names called domain1.com and domain2.com, those are second-level registrations thus *you cannot use a CNAME for those* as they are by definition zone apex domains which have SOA and NS records attached.  CNAMEs are illegal with any other record types.